# What's wrong with my guard-based haskell code for halving a list?

Tags: list, haskell

Here is the code:

```
    listhalve :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
listhalve (x:xs)
    | length [x] == length xs = ([x],xs)
    | length [x] <  length xs = listhalve ([x] ++ head xs : tail xs)
    | length [x] > length xs = ([x],xs)
```

There are no error messages when I run or compile it, it just runs forever in the case of non-pair lists.

I'm aware of different ways to write this function that work. I just want to know what's wrong with this code *specifically*.

Upon taking your comments to heart, I came up with this code here:

```
listhalve :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
listhalve xs = listhalve' [] xs
    where
        listhalve' :: [a] -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
        listhalve' x y
            | length x == length y = (x, y)
            | length x <  length y = listhalve' (x ++ (head y)) (tail y)
            | length x >  length y = (x, y)
```

This gives me an error reading:

```
test.hs:7:56: error:
    * Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a1 ~ [a1]
    * In the second argument of `(++)', namely `(head y)'
      In the first argument of listhalve', namely `(x ++ (head y))'
      In the expression: listhalve' (x ++ (head y)) (tail y)
    * Relevant bindings include
        y :: [a1] (bound at test.hs:5:22)
        x :: [a1] (bound at test.hs:5:20)
        listhalve' :: [a1] -> [a1] -> ([a1], [a1]) (bound at test.hs:5:9)
  |
7 |             | length x <  length y = listhalve' (x ++ (head y)) (tail y)
  |
```

What's the problem with this code?

Comment: `length [x]` is a obfuscated way of writing `1`.

Comment: `listhalve ([x] ++ head xs : tail xs)` is basically just `listhalve (x:xs)`.

Comment: Also, your pattern-matching is not exhaustive. You may wish to add `listhalve [] = ([], [])`.

Comment: @Chris 

Really, I thought that it would increase the length of x by one, and decrease the length of xs by one, until they were equal or x was longer than xs.

Comment: `x` is always a single element of a list, not a sublist. You seem to think the recursive call is made on something like `[[x], xs]`, which wouldn't type check. You need to operate on a tuple of lists from the beginning. Consider using a recursive helper like `go :: [a] -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`, where `listhalve xs = go [] xs` Each call to `go` should "transfer" an element from its second argument to its first, until the two arguments have lengths that are close enough.

Comment: Your `listhalve'` function has two guards that lead to the same result. You could consolidate them with: `length x >= length y`. At which point you only have one other option, and you can replace that with `otherwise`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider that `listhalve ([x] ++ head xs : tail xs)` is the same as `listhalve ([x] ++ xs)` which is the same as `listhalve (x:xs)` which is what you went in with, so endless recursion results.

Comment: Thanks. I thought for some reason that     listhalve (x:xs)     was a function of  two variables. I'll write up a similar function later, using two arguments.

Comment: A fun little one-liner playing around in GHCi:  `halve lst = foldl (\(a1, a2) _ -> let d = length a1 - length a2 in if d <= 1 && d >= -1 then (a1, a2) else (a1 ++ [head a2], tail a2)) ([], lst) lst`. It's not especially efficient, but maybe you can take somethign from it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is fixed, and the second function works, when you specify `head y` to be a list, i.e. `[head y]`. The full, corrected function looks like this:

```
listhalve :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
listhalve xs = listhalve' [] xs
    where
        listhalve' :: [a] -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
        listhalve' x y
            | length x == length y = (x, y)
            | length x <  length y = listhalve' (x ++ [head y]) (tail y)
            | length x >  length y = (x, y)
```